# How can a rename a share on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing, rename

We would like to rename a share - not the folder, just the name of the Share itself - on a Windows 2003 Server. If I right-click on the folder name and go to the properties dialog, I can see the share name, but it's there as a dropdown list, not an editable textbox.

Is the only way to 'rename' a share like this to delete the current share and then recreate a new one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the sharing tab of the properties dialog there is a New Share button at the bottom that will add a new share name into that drop-down.  This will allow you to create a new share and set the share to that new name without having to delete the existing share.

Don't forget to review the share permissions on the new share when doing this.  Also if you don't need the old share be sure and delete it to keep things clean and secure.

Comment: **Win2012-Win2019:** Explorer `->` right-click on the folder `->` Properties `->` Sharing `->` Advanced Sharing... `->` Add/Remove.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to delete the share and re-create.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, in the **Computer Management** administrative tool, under the path *System Tools* > *Shared Folders* > *Shares*, you can right-click and create several shares pointing at the same folder, as well as remove them. The difference here is that the interface is designed around shares rather than folders.

Answer (score 2):

Look this:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\Shares
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\lanmanserver\Shares

Try to rename and restart

Answer (score 1):

It looks like under Sharing and Security you have to unshare it, then reshare it and you can change the name. This means you'll have to make note of your Share Permissions to redo those.

Answer (score 0):

Create new share and test it.  If all works, than delete the old share.

Don't delete old share until you know the new one works.